# How to change product status from sql using SKU

Tags: magento2, product, sql, query

I need to disable and enable a huge quantity of products filtering by sku and the easiest solution seem to be through Sql query but i have some issues to find the right code

For example i need to disable 10000 products Sku: 001, 002, 003, 004, etc... i've found the right code for magento 1.9 but for magento 2 it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable product by using `SKU`. First of all find the `attribute_id` value for status.
For find the correct attribute_id run this command in sql

```
select `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` AS `attribute_id`, `catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` AS `entity_id`, `catalog_product_entity_int`.`value` AS `value`, `catalog_product_entity`.`sku` AS `sku` from ((`eav_attribute` join `catalog_product_entity_int` on ((`eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = `catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id`))) join `catalog_product_entity` on ((`catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`))) where ((`eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'status') and (`catalog_product_entity_int`.`value` = 1))
```

The first value (for me was 97 ) is the correct attribute_id to replace at **XXX**

Copy the Attribute id and paste it in the SQL query run it in phpMyAdmin.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int a, catalog_product_entity b
SET a.value = "2"
WHERE b.entity_id = a.entity_id
AND b.sku LIKE '%SKU%'
AND a.attribute_id = **XXX**
```

After running the query Login to your admin and go to

System > Cache Management - >  Clear Cache
System > Index management > Rebuild Catalog Index

Also

You can also change status massively via products grid: check the boxes for items -> `Actions - Change status -> Enable/Disable`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply, i've already tried with this code but returns 0 row updated

Comment: You can also disable products using csv in magento

Comment: i have updated answer.

Comment: yes i know this option but even if rare this time i should disable over 17000 product and select one for one is impossible for me

Comment: UPDATE ma_catalog_product_entity_int
SET VALUE = '2'
WHERE attribute_id = 80 //product status attribute it.
AND entity_id IN (SELECT sku FROM ma_catalog_product_entity);

Comment: Does it work or not ?

Comment: always 0 row updated i've removed the ma_ extension and edit the attirubute_id but no working